# Which way is better to get a response from http and why?

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, java-io

I would like to know where the general difference is in this two ways of getting the response from a http call.

The following are Android examples but in Java it's quite the same.

First example using only the `org.apache.http` library:

```
String s = "";

try {

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    s = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);

    // do something with s      
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second example using a BufferedReader to get the response:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                instream));

try {
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        // do something with the stringbuilder

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In which scenarios I should prefer the second example using a Stream and a Reader over the first example and vice versa? There are some major thoughts why I ask this question. If there is a important point not included please tell me:

1. The Reader approach takes way more space and time.
2. The size of the response data has no effect on the first or second example.
3. The code in the second example is more complicated (has more overhead).
4. The Reader approach is way more flexibel, because of the amount of different Readers in the library.

This points make me favor the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probable that any differences in the performance of the two versions will not be significant to your application's overall performance.  (It *might* be significant if the response body is really large, but even then performance is likely to be dominated by network latency and bandwidth considerations.)

Assuming that performance differences are unlikely to be significant, the other thing to consider are how maintainable the code is; i.e. how easy is it to read, and modify.  My feeling is that the first version is simpler and therefore easier to get right and easier to maintain.

---

> 1) The Reader approach takes way more space and time.

Not necessarily.  The difference (if any) will be in the way that the data is accumulated before the result string is created.  If the HTTP response includes a Content-length header, then it is *possible* that the first version can preallocate a `byte[]` of the right size.  By contrast, the second version is accumulating data in a `StringBuilder` which is likely to entail multiple rounds of reallocation / copying of the builder's backing array.  (The extra work is `O(N)` so it does not alter the overall measure of computational complexity.  But it still impacts on performance ... and memory usage.)

> 2) The size of the response data has no effect on the first or second example.

Incorrect.  It has an effect in both cases.  (Obviously ... a long response takes longer to read than a short response ... in both cases!!)

> 3) The code in the second example is more complicated (has more overhead).

It is more complicated, but that doesn't imply there is more overhead.  In the first case, there is complexity too, but it is not in code that *you* have to write.  But anyway, simplicity does not necessarily mean greater efficiency / lower overheads.  That's not how performance works ...

> 4) The Reader approach is way more flexible, because of the amount of different Readers in the library.

Irrelevant.  In this case you've made a good choice of the `Reader` classes.  Flexibility doesn't make any difference here.

---

There are other problems:

- Both versions assume that the response body is text.
- The first version assumes that the response body is encoded in UTF-8.
- The second version assumes that response body is encoded using the (local) platform's default encoding.
- The second version gobbles up the line breaks.  That's a bug.

---

Explanation of the bug:  The readLine() method reads a line and returns it without the line separator.  Your code then adds it to the `StringBuilder` ... without adding a line separator.  The end result is that the `StringBuilder` contains the data with all line separators removed.  Ooops!

Comment: I agree, that the code should be maintainable and easy understandable.  And the first approach is, if I can say so, the overall default way. So, if I know how to do it better the second approach should be used? At least could you plz elaborate "Incorrect. It has an effect in both cases." and "The second version gobbles up the line breaks. That's a bug."? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

The first example uses Apache `EntityUtils` to read the stream in a String. From the code, what it does is it uses a `Reader` to read in a fixed size `char[]` the content from the `entity.getContent()`, and appends it to a form of Buffer.

The second example reads line by line using a `BufferedReader`.

1. The `BufferedReader` may not take more space in itself, but the amount of space necessary to bufferize is unknown, because it requires reading a line (i.e. until a line break is found), and there may not be any line break in the response. This entire line is buffered, then read to a String, then appended, making it present 3 times in memory.
2. Agreed
3. The code of the `BufferedReader` example is obviously longer.
4. Any approach that does not use a third part method is more flexible, because you can work on the content of the stream without waiting to have read the entire thing
5. The `readLine` approach has another defect, which is of loosing the line break characters. In some cases they may carry information.

If you want an efficient yet flexible approach, look at the actual implementation from apache [EntityUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java#EntityUtils.toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity,java.lang.String%29). It uses a fixed size char[] for buffering, ensuring that you know the amount of memory overhead, and it reads all the characters, including the line breaks.

`readLine` really is useful only when you need to read a line. (!)

(The relevant part of the implementation:)

```
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, charset);
    CharArrayBuffer buffer = new CharArrayBuffer(i);
    try {
        char[] tmp = new char[1024];
        int l;
        while((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: The essence of you answer is, what I understood, if I know that the response has line breaks the Reader approach should be prefered? Because I can set up the reader for the situation. That would assume that I know the data, which I request or not?

Comment: both are `Readers`. The `BufferedReader.readLine` is only useful if you need to handle the content line by line and don't care about the line break characters. Otherwise, it is useless at best.

Comment: IMHO, there are 3 general options when receiving data from a Server. Option A (simple), the response is a String, not too long (exact definition of 'not too long' may vary, I currently place it a ~1Mo). In this case, the EntityUtils approach is perfect. Simple, short to write, efficient. Option B, you receive a very long String. Use an InputStreamReader your self, handle the String part by part. It can be a JSON stream, Base64 ... Option C, you receive binary, in which case a Reader is inappropriate. Use a basic InputStream and handle the content directly.